# How to remove additional header in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation

When I added navigation, suddenly I have two headers. How do I remove the "index" header.

index.js:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, ScrollView, SafeAreaView, Text, Button, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack'

import Home from './home';
import styles from '../myComponents/common/header/header/header.style';
import { COLORS, icons, images, FONT, SIZES } from '../constants';
import { ScreenHeaderBtn, TimeSlider, SessionBtn } from '../myComponents';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function App() {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
            <Stack.Navigator>
                <Stack.Group screenOptions={{
                        headerStyle: { backgroundColor: COLORS.lightBeige },
                        headerShadowVisible: true,
                        headerLeft: () => (
                            <ScreenHeaderBtn iconUrl={icons.menu} dimension="60%" />
                        ),
                        headerTitle: () => (
                            <Text style={styles.headerStyle}>
                                Flowtime
                            </Text>
                        ),
                        headerTitleAlign: 'center',
                    }}>
                    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
                </Stack.Group>
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
};

export default App;
```

home.js

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, ScrollView, SafeAreaView, Text, Button } from 'react-native';

import styles from '../myComponents/common/header/header/header.style';
import { COLORS, icons, images, FONT, SIZES } from '../constants';
import { ScreenHeaderBtn, TimeSlider, SessionBtn } from '../myComponents';

function Home() {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: COLORS.lightBeige }}>
            <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
                <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: SIZES.medium, }}>

                    <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', padding: SIZES.xLarge }}>
                        <SessionBtn />
                    </View>
                    <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', padding: SIZES.xLarge }}>
                        <TimeSlider />
                    </View>

                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

[image: Screenshot]

If I remove independent={true} from the NavigationContainer I get this:

"Error: Looks like you have nested a 'NavigationContainer' inside another. Normally you need only one container at the root of the app, so this was probably an error. If this was intentional, pass 'independent={true}' explicitly. Note that this will make the child navigators disconnected from the parent and you won't be able to navigate between them."

So I believe I need to find the other supposed another NavigationContainer and place an options={{headerShown:false}} within it but the problem is that this NavigationContainer is the only one I put in my entire project. So I have no idea how else to get this other "index" header above my intended to disappear... Perhaps the additional header is caused by the phantom NavigationContainer and in that case, how can I find it and remove it, cause I literally just installed NavigationContainer and implemented a total of one NavigationContainer yet I am getting this error that this NavigationContainer is inside another which sounds impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code It will show one header only:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Search"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Search')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function EmptyScreen() {
  return <View />;
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Group
          screenOptions={{
                        headerStyle: { backgroundColor: 'red' },
                        headerShadowVisible: true,
                        headerLeft: () => (
                            <Text>Icon</Text>
                        ),
                        headerTitle: () => (
                            <Text>
                                Flowtime
                            </Text>
                        ),
                        headerTitleAlign: 'center',
                    }}
        >
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={EmptyScreen} />
        </Stack.Group>
        <Stack.Group screenOptions={{ presentation: 'modal' }}>
          <Stack.Screen name="Search" component={EmptyScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Share" component={EmptyScreen} />
        </Stack.Group>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

For more details, you can find details [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/group).

Comment: I cant use this as I mentioned above "If I remove independent={true} from the NavigationContainer I get this:

"Error: Looks like you have nested a 'NavigationContainer' inside another. Normally you need only one container at the root of the app, so this was probably an error. If this was intentional, pass 'independent={true}' explicitly. Note that this will make the child navigators disconnected from the parent and you won't be able to navigate between them."".

Comment: you must have to use only one NavigationContainer for best practices and inside that manages stack group according to your requirement so your problem is solved

Comment: I used only one NavigationContainer, that's the problem! Anyway I tried starting a different environment and implementing my code and now I guess it works but I'm still curious as to the real issue here.

Comment: You can refer independent documentation from here at last https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-container/